# Why is lookup in an Array O(1)?

Tags: ruby, arrays, big-o

I believe that in some languages other than Ruby, an Array lookup is O(1) because you know where the data starts, and you multiply the index by the size of the data the array is holding, and then access that memory location.

However, in Ruby, an Array can have objects from different classes, so how does it manage to do a lookup of O(1) complexity?

Comment: Your first paragraph contradicted your second paragraph, so I edited to make it not contradictory. If you have particular language in mind that you did not mention, then make that clear.

Comment: sawa, you are more than right. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What @Neil Slater said, with a little more detail…

There are basically two plausible approaches to storing an array of heterogeneous objects of differing sizes:

1. Store the objects as a singly- or doubly-[linked list](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/linked_list), with the storage space for each individual object preceded by pointer(s) to the preceding and/or following objects. This structure has the advantage of making it very easy to insert new objects at arbitrary points without shifting around the rest of the array, but the huge downside is that looking up an object by its position is generally `O(N)`, since you have to start from one end of the list and jump through it node-by-node until you arrive at the *n*-th one.
2. Store a table or array of constant-sized pointers to the individual objects. Since this lookup table contains constant-sized items in a contiguous ordered layout, looking up the addresses of individual objects `O(1)`; the table is just a C-style array, in which lookup only takes 1-to-a-few machine instructions, even on RISC CPU architectures.

(The allocation strategies for storing the individual objects are also interesting and complex, but not immediately relevant to your question.)

Dynamic languages like Perl/Python/Ruby pretty much **all opt for #2** for their general-purpose list/array types. In other words, they make lookup more efficient than inserting objects at random locations in the list, which is the better choice for many applications.

I'm not familiar with the implementation details for Ruby, but they are likely quite similar to those of Python's `list` type, whose performance and design is explained in wonderful detail at [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#performance).

Answer (score 4):

Its implementation probably contains an array of memory addresses, pointing to the actual objects. Therefore it can still lookup without looping through the array.

Comment: For MRI Ruby and Rubinius: Internally *all* Ruby objects are the same base type in C (referred in a `#define` called `VALUE`, so it could change in some implementations). Sometimes a `VALUE` is treated as a pointer, sometimes (e.g. for small integers) is a coded value of the item. It is these fixed-length `VALUE` terms that get stored in an Array though. If you include that detail, you can drop the *probably*.

Comment: @NeilSlater Put your comment as proper answer :D I'll delete my guess-answer.